# Python: compare folders and move similar folders

Tags: python, directory, move, shutil

I am trying to compare two folders with different data and files where a backup was done and not all the files and folders got moved correctly.

There are two data sources `dir1` and `dir2`, would like the script to find data in dir1 and if the folder doesn't exist it moves the whole folder to a move folder location, but if it exists then compares the contents of the folder and then moves the unmatched data into the move folder and the similar data to the delete folder location.

I have tried several ways to do this and am stuck, the only point I could get to is moving the directories between the two sources but when it comes to comparing the files between the two sources and moving them is kinda challenging. Have spent time trying different methods from the forum but got no luck yet. I have added what I have so far.

```py
import os, shutil, filecmp, fnmatch, glob, zipfile, sys, time, re

dir1 = r'C:\ZZZ\Test1'
dir2 = r'C:\ZZZ\Test2'

FolderMove = r'C:\ZZZ\Move'
FolderDelete = r'C:\ZZZ\Delete'

from os.path import join, isfile

dir1_folders = [dir for dir in os.listdir(dir1) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dir1, dir))]
dir2_folders = [dir for dir in os.listdir(dir2) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dir2, dir))]

for dir in dir1_folders:
    if dir not in dir2_folders:
        shutil.move(os.path.join(dir1, dir), os.path.join(FolderMove, dir))
    print dir

for dir in dir1_folders:
    if dir in dir2_folders:
        shutil.move(os.path.join(dir1, dir), os.path.join(FolderDelete, dir))
    print dir
```

Comment: Rather than write your own utility for this, there are lots of free utilities out there for this. WinMerge is one that I use on Windows, or try one of these (http://www.linuxalt.com/linux-alternatives-to/windows/winmerge.html) similar tools on Linux.

Comment: Thank you @PaulMcGuire will definitely look into it. Thank you once again and have a nice day.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Have checked out the application and it only works with two folder while i need something that copies the difference to a third or fourth folder.